# system drawing image is undefined?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, system.drawing

Ive used the post in Free Barcode API for .NET from Andrei Schneider...

```
BarcodeLib.Barcode barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode()
    {
        IncludeLabel = true,
        Alignment = AlignmentPositions.CENTER,
        Width = 300,
        Height = 100,
        RotateFlipType = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone,
        BackColor = Color.White,
        ForeColor = Color.Black,
    };

    model.BarcodeImage = barcode.Encode(TYPE.CODE128B, "123456789");
```

then in view `@Model.BarcodeImage`

but this throws errro:

```
 Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Drawing.Image' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Source Error:




Line 54:                             </td>
Line 55:                             <td width="30%">
Line 56:                                 @Model.BarcodeImage
Line 57:                             </td>
Line 58:                         </tr>
```

and I have referenced system.drawing in project??

Comment: Which .NET version is your project targeting? If it's anything other than 4.0, that's your problem.

Comment: I checked it, my target framework is 4....what now ?

Comment: Why don't you do as adviced in the compile error and add a reference to System.Drawing in your project?

Comment: You should be careful - you're going down an unsupported route: [System.Drawing Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx): "Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components."

Comment: Could you show your model code?